# Dynamic iframes in React web app

Tags: reactjs, iframe, web-applications

I asked this as part of a larger question at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/373520/help-defining-architecture-async-messaging-web-app-as-portal-in-web-page.  Though with no responses I thought I'd reduce the complexity of the main part of the question to a pure technical one.

I'd like to have one or more web-apps as 'portal's within an outer web app.  In HTML5 this could be achieved with `<iframe`.  However the solution I'm desiring is more dynamic than this with the internal web-apps not known ahead of time.

Are there any solutions to this problem?  I'm happy to consider any options though a React one preferred.  Perhaps i'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: If you could achieve this with `<ifame>` in HTML5... why cant you do the same in react?

Comment: Because I want to have dynamic behaviour - the `src` won't be known until runtime.

Comment: And until the `src` is known, what would you like to do? render something else instead of the diff?

Comment: Or nothing at all.  Imagine the use case that various Publishers have sent messages to offer an alternative web-app that satisfies the requirement.  Each of these is added to a drop-down and after the user selects the desired one, that app is used as the source.   Mmm, I wonder if you can change the `src` value on the fly.

Comment: If you want to render nothing, return null in render. I updated my answer accordingly. As long as your pure component is aware of the newly valued `src` and is set as a state, it will rerender the component and therefore show the latest iframe containing the latest `src` value. Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your problem is quite simple. Does the following make sense to you? if it does not, please let me know.

```
render() {
   const { iFrameSrc } = this.state
   // if You have the source, return the iframe
   if (iFrameSrc) return <iframe src={iFrameSrc} />

   // if you dont have the source, render default
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes I think that follows along the line of the comment I just added - updating the source attribute.  I'll try that out (it is a side project and will get back to shortly). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yep that tactic works just great.  I created 3 web apps and include #2 or #3 in #1 with an `iframe` and swap one to the other and vv with a click of  a button.  Next I"ll try wiring to messages.  Thanks heaps for this simple and obvious solution (when you are trying to wrap your head around bigger pictures sometimes you miss the small stuff).